# Using jquery can I how can i find out when a bootstrap alert is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to run some code when a bootstrap alert is closed however, no matter what I try I cannot get it to work.

I need some code that will allow me to know when someone closes the alert box.

Comment: $(document).on('close', ".alert" ,function  () 
   {
    //console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    if($(this).attr("id") == "1"){
     protein_amt++;
    }
   });

Thats what i have so far.

Comment: Why are you adding the handler to `document` object and not to the alert element itself

Comment: i actually created the alert dynamically using jquery -

$("#sel_items").append('<li><div  style="height: 40%; width: 40%;" class="alert alert-info"><a id='+ $(this).attr("class") +' class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>"'+ $(this).text() +'"</div><li>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to bind the `closed` event to the document. The closed event is triggered after the element is detached from the dom tree(`$parent.detach().trigger('closed.bs.alert').remove()`) so it will not get propagated up the dom tree to the document so the handlers attached to document object will not get triggered.

If you want to use the `closed` event, you need to bind it to the alert element itself

```
$('.alert').on('closed.bs.alert', function(e) {

});
```

another solution is to use the `close` event, but it is triggered before the element is removed so there is a possibility that the element removed might be prevented by some handler(by calling `event.preventDefault()`)

```
$(document).on('close.bs.alert', '.alert', function(e) {
});
```

```js
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert closed.bs.alert', function(e) {
  snippet.log('alert: ' + e.namespace + '.' + e.type);
});
$(document).on('close.bs.alert closed.bs.alert', '.alert', function(e) {
  snippet.log('doc: ' + e.namespace + '.' + e.type);
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br />
<br />
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
  <h4>Oh snap! You got an error!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me ans the explanation was great too

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Bootstrap alert events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-events) which will fire when the alert is closing or has closed.

```
$('#myAlert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
  // do something…
})
```